# Changing mouse scroll speed

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, mouse, scrolling, x

I'm trying to change the mouse scroll speed. Currently it's way too slow. I'm using GNOME 3.32 and there are no obvious settings to adapt that. Ideally I would like to change it at the system level, so I can use other window managers as well.

This is the output I get from `xinput list-props 11` with 11 being my mouse (classified under virtual pointer):

```
  Device 'SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 310 eSports Mouse':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (289):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (290):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (296): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (297): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (298):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (299):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (300): -0.125000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (301): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (302):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (303):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (304):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (305): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (306): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (274): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (275):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (276):    0, 0
    Device Node (277):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (278):    4152, 5920
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (291):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (292):   1
```

On other threats it seems that it could be fixed with `evdev` settings but my mouse does not seem to have those and so obviously doing the following doesn't work:

```
xinput set-prop 11 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 10 10 10
property 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can increase the mouse speed in a proper way? 
I'm currently using `imwheel` as temporary hack, but I don't consider this a good long-term solution.

Thank you

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe this can be configured with [libratbag](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag) in combination with [Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/)? They list your Rival 310 as [supported](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/wiki/Devices#steelseries-devices).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but after installing both programs and combing through it, it seems that there is no option to adjust the scrolling speed unfortunately. Am I missing something?

Comment: Question is not completely clear: do you need a system-wide solution or a GNOME solution?

Comment: system wide is ideal, if not, then gnome specific is also ok